# Unable to connect to Docker container: Connection Refused

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, tomcat, amazon-ec2, docker-machine

I have a war file deployed as `Docker` container on `linux ec2`. But when I try to hit the `http://ec2-elastic-ip:8080/AppName`, I don't get any response.

I have all the `security group` inbound rules set up for both `http` and `https`. So that's not a problem.

**Debugging**

I tried debugging by `ssh-ing` the linux instance. Tried command `curl localhost:8080` , this is the response:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused
```

Tried with `127.0.0.1:8080` but the same response.

Next thing I did was to list the Docker container: `docker ps`. I get:

```
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE  COMMAND  CREATED  STATUS   PORTS   NAMES
<ID>        <ecr>.amazonaws.com/<my>-registry:2019-05-16.12-17-02   "catalina.sh run"   24 minutes ago      Up 24 minutes       0.0.0.0:32772->8080/tcp   ecs-app-24-name
```

Now, I connected to this container using `docker exec -it <name> /bin/bash` and tried checking tomcat logs which clearly shows that my application war is there and tomcat has started.

I ever tried checking the `docker-machine ip default` but this gave me error:

```
Docker machine "default" does not exist. Use "docker-machine ls" to list machines. Use "docker-machine create" to add a new one.
```

Now am stuck. Not able to debug further. The result am expecting is to access the app through the url above.

What to do? Is it something am doing wrong?

Also, to mention, the entire infrastructure is managed through `terraform`. I first create the base image,copy the war to webapps using `DockerFile`, push the registry image and finally do a `terraform apply` to apply any changes.

Comment: is the deployed app inside the container suppose to run in port 32772? if not, you need to `EXPOSE <port>`  the port where the application is running inside the Dockerfile. Then, when doing the docker run or docker-compose up, map the port `-p <port> 8080`

Comment: It should suppose to run on 8080. That is what I had specified in my `ecs` module task-definitions. `"portMappings": [
      {
        "hostport": 0,
        "containerport": 8080
      }
    ]`

Comment: so in your Dockerfile, do you have `EXPOSE 8080`?

Comment: No. Docker file just adds, from the registry image,  a war file to `/usr/local/tomcat/webapps'

Comment: then that's what you need :)

Comment: Expose the port and bind it as well `$ docker run -p 8080:8080`

Comment: @workaround Am looking for a one time solution. Do I need to bind it every time I do a new deployment?

Comment: @roger_that Do you run your container by just running the image or do you you a coompose file?

Comment: just so we are clear on this.. Dockerfile EXPOSE is just meta data for informational purpose - it isn't a binding in of itself.  Linux hosts reflect on that info on the image for binding, but orchestrators (like docker compose) should specify the binds and not rely on that host specific behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that apache is listening on all IP addresses inside the docker container, not just localhost. The IP should be like 0.0.0.0.

If any service is running inside docker and is listening to only localhost, it can only be accessed inside that container, not from the host.

You can also try to start apache with port 8080 and bind docker 8080 port with host 8080 port

```
docker run apache -p 8080:8080
```

Comment: How do we make sure of that? And will I need to do this every time I do the deployment?

Comment: Can you specify which apache image you are using?

Comment: Its a web server. Tomcat.

Comment: docker run -it --rm -p 8080:8080 tomcat:8.0

Answer (score 1):

Currently your app is working on a random host port i.e `32772`, see the `docker ps` output .You must be able to access you app on `http://ec2-ip:32772` once you allow port `32772` in security groups.

In order to make it work on host port 8080, you need to bind/expose the host port during docker run -

`$ docker run -p 8080:8080 ......`

If you are on ECS, ideally you should use an ALB & TG with your service.

However, if you are not using ALB etc then you can try giving a static hostPort in TD `"hostPort": 8080`(I haven't tried this). If it works fine, you will need to make sure to change the deployment strategy as "minimum healthy percentage = 0" else you might face port conflict issues.

Comment: Will I have to do this every time I deploy?

Comment: yes, whenever you run a new container. To make things easy, you can use `docker compose` going forward. You may create an alias for such commands.

Comment: I do specify port `8080` on my ecs task definition inside terrafor infra. Shouldn't that suppose to take this every time?

Comment: That's a separate issue. You can use target groups and make host port `0` to ensure your ALB redirects to the right set of host:port. You define the ALB in the service definition which inturn takes care of port allocation on host etc.

Comment: That's the point. Am not using ALB. Specified a public ip to ec2. And the port mapping is: `"portMappings": [ { "hostport": 0, "containerport": 8080 } ]`

Comment: You just need to define the container port in creating a service via terraform & use host port as `0` in task definition.

Comment: Try giving a static hostPort in TD `"hostPort": 8080`. I haven't tried that. If it works fine, you will need to make sure that while deploying you make the strategy "minimum healthy percentage = 0" else you might face port conflict issues.

Comment: What was the error? However, it seems like using an ALB in front would be the best bet for now.

Comment: I don't have that much of traffic, so avoiding ALB for extra cost. Error is same.

Answer (score 1):

If the application needs a network port you must **EXPOSE** it in the docker file.

```
EXPOSE <port> [<port>/<protocol>...]
```

In case you need that port to be mapped to a specific port on the network, you must define that when you spin up the new container.

```
docker run -p 8080:8080/tcp  my_app
```

If you use run each image separately you must bind the port every time.
If you don't want to do this every time you can use **docker-compose** and add the ports directive in it.

```
ports:
 - "8080:8080/tcp"
```

Supposing you added expose in the dockerfile, he full docker-compose.yml would look like this:

```
version: '1'
services:
  web:
    build:
    ports:
    - "8080:8080"
    my_app:
    image: my_app
```

Comment: This is not entirely accurate. You don't _have_ to include an `EXPOSE` instruction - you _should_ add it for documentation.